# Firefox + Selenium WebDriver and download a csv file automatically

Tags: python, firefox, csv, selenium, webdriver

I have problem with Selenium WebDriver and Firefox. I want to download csv file without confirmation in dialog window and I have code like this:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv")
```

but it seems not working. 
I tried many combination with **browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk**

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv,application/csv,text/plan,text/comma-separated-values")
```

or

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/csv")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/plain")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/comma-separated-values")
```

but there's no difference and Firefox won't download automaticly.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes, that was problem with a wrong MIME type, thanks!

Comment: can anyone help me?
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27058053/selenium-python-webdriver-path-error-system-cant-find-the-path-specified

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometime the content type is not as you'd expect
Use **HttpFox** Firefox plugin (or similar) to find the real content type of the file and use it in your code

BTW, For me the content type was

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/octet-stream");
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: I faced the same issue as @nanoo. Used HttpFox & determined that the mime type was application/msexcel. Works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/comma-separated-values ,text/csv");   //in java selenium
 this will work for downloading all type of csv files...
thanks, enjoy....

Answer (score 0):

Now (May 2016),

```
 SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv"); // C#
```

works for me