# Downloading file to specified location with Selenium and python

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ok so far i have my programing going to the website i want to download link from and selecting it, then the firefox dialogue box shows up and i don't know what to do. i want to save this file to a folder on my desktop. I am using this for a nightly build so i need this to work. Please help.

Here is my code that grabs the download link from the website:

```
driver = web driver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("Name of web site I'm grabbing from")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEV.tgz')]".click()
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need to make `Firefox` save this particular file type automatically.

This can be achieved by setting `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` preference:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'PATH TO DESKTOP')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("Name of web site I'm grabbing from")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEV.tgz')]").click()
```

More explanation:

- `browser.download.folderList` tells it not to use default `Downloads` directory
- `browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting` turns of showing download progress
- `browser.download.dir` sets the directory for downloads
- `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` tells Firefox to automatically download the files of the selected `mime-types`

You can view all these preferences at `about:config` in the browser. There is also a very detailed documentation page available here: [About:config entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries).

Besides, instead of using `xpath` approach, I would use [`find_element_by_partial_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_partial_link_text):

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("DEV.tgz").click()
```

Also see:

- [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)
- [Firefox + Selenium WebDriver and download a csv file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759762/firefox-selenium-webdriver-and-download-a-csv-file-automatically)

Comment: I am getting an error on the 'profile = webdriver.FFP' line, IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: @JeradBill this is something to do with your particular code. Not the one I've provided.

Comment: Any good idea on doing so in a `WebDriver` agnostic way? (e.g. `Firefox` and `PhantomJS` interchangeably)

Comment: Is it possible to set `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` to all files? I don't know about the file type I download.

Comment: @Blaszard Set browser.download.useDownloadDir to True.

Comment: @alecxe what is equivalent of option `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` for chromdriver?

Comment: How to specify more than one mimetype in "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk"? By comma-separating the values?

Comment: How do I use this in IE?

Comment: If you are trying to download files with no specified mimetype, e.g.: `.dmp`, you may use mimetype `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 3):

[@alecxe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251803/1107226) updated - `firefox_profile` has been deprecated; this answer works as of March 2023, Firefox 110, Python 3.9, Selenium 4.8.2:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'PATH TO DESKTOP')
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("Name of web site I'm grabbing from")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'DEV.tgz')]").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

If the application is generated dynamically (mime-types) using Chrome browser will be a better approach since the Chrome will not open the file download pop-up.But multiple download option should be enabled if you need multiple downloads.

Comment: I am trying to do this same thing using Chrome, but I am having trouble setting the location of where to download the file. The same Profile functionality doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to set the download location in Chrome?

Comment: chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory",downloadFilepath);

_ChromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);

Comment: @niNa how about `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` ?