# Selenium firefox profile update download directory after creating webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I'm wondering how can I update/change download location in selenium once I started driver?

it is not problem to set download dir during creation of profile and initiation of webdriver. The problem appears after initiation of webdriver to change directory depending on data type.

For example 
-if dl doc is word save in Docs\Word
-if dl doc is pdf save in Docs\pdf

this is my code

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/download,application/octet-stream,application/pdf')
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
sleep(10)
# this part doesn't work
driver.profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir',"{0}\{1}".format(os.getcwd(),"Docs"))
driver.profile.update_preferences()
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible through Selenium, see discussion here [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/_uJeXWJHAaI]

Comment: huh I will try several more combinations after that I will have to make a workaround.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downloading file to specified location with Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251583/downloading-file-to-specified-location-with-selenium-and-python)

Comment: it not duplicate...in that post he didn't know how to set download location using selenium. I'm looking to change download dir after initiate of driver that already has another dl dir location. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Firefox it's possible to change the preferences at run-time with a scrip injection once the context is set to `chrome`:

```
def set_download_dir(driver, directory):
  driver.command_executor._commands["SET_CONTEXT"] = ("POST", "/session/$sessionId/moz/context")
  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "chrome"})

  driver.execute_script("""
    Services.prefs.setBoolPref('browser.download.useDownloadDir', true);
    Services.prefs.setStringPref('browser.download.dir', arguments[0]);
    """, directory)

  driver.execute("SET_CONTEXT", {"context": "content"})
```

Comment: I just tested and it works like charm...Do you have any idea is it possible to use script injection for the name change of the file that is curenttly dl ?

Comment: It's not possible to preset the name.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!