# Setting Selenium FirefoxProfile settings not consistent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to set up a Firefox(Windows, 61.0) profile for use in Selenium WebDriver (3.13.0) with Java so that Firefox automatically downloads files so that I can bypass download dialogs.

Here's the code:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir",true);
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/x-download");
return options.setProfile(profile);
```

`browser.download.folderList` and `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` both affect the settings you'd expect them to affect, but in the case of `browser.download.useDownloadDir`, it doesn't affect the actual setting (i.e. it remains false). Rather, it creates a new, similar (?) setting called `services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.useDownloadDir`.

[image]

Any idea what the issue is here, and how I can set the useDownloadDir setting to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:** Specify the mime type of downloaded files. This is an example for XLS / XLSX files:

```
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = new FirefoxProfile();
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\BP_usr_tmp\\");
selenium_profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
```

**OPTION 2:** Use an existing Firefox profile. With existing profile "selenium_profile" I use this:

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();         
        FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
        options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
        options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\geckodriver-v0.20.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }
```

Use Firefox profile manager (Win+R: firefox -p) to create a new profile. Run Firefox in the new profile and set up customizations you need including autodownload for specific file types.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by setting those prefs during runtime as described in this post:

[Selenium firefox profile update download directory after creating webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213750/selenium-firefox-profile-update-download-directory-after-creating-webdriver)

My issue is likely caused by the enterprise settings on my machine, which could force prefs to default a certain way each time a new window opens regardless of what's passed to the browser via Selenium. For example, I wasn't able to edit browser.download.useDownloadDir, browser.download.dir, and browser.download.folderList (among others). My mime types were set correctly and the issue still occurred on my end.