# Selenium + Firefox + Python: Download Directory issue

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, download

I have read these QA :

[Downloading file to specified location with Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251583/downloading-file-to-specified-location-with-selenium-and-python)

[Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

and this blog : [Working with file download in Python Selenium WebDriver](http://allselenium.info/file-downloads-python-selenium-webdriver/)

I then executed this code to specify the right path for the download:

```
from selenium import webdriver

my_path = r'C\some_dir\where_I\want_to\store\the_downloads'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("brower.download.foldeList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", my_path)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv/pdf")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, firefox_profile=profile)
```

My issue is that the documents are not saved in `my_path` but in the default download directory of firefox.

**EDIT 1:**

I am unable to change the `browser.download.folderList` parameter.

Here is my command:

```
profile.set_preference('brower.download.folderList', '2')
```

I also tried each of these:

```
profile.set_preference('brower.download.folderList', 2)
profile.set_preference("brower.download.folderList", '2')
profile.set_preference("brower.download.folderList", 2)
```

When I open the `about:config` page on the opened Firefow window, `brower.download.folderList` is set to `1`.

Comment: You could try with my_path = r'C:\\some_dir\\where_I\\want_to\\store\\the_downloads' (missing colon added in the path and backslashes escaped)

Comment: also typos here: ...brower.download.foldeList", 2  May also want to try just "..." instead of "text/csv/pdf" for all types.

Comment: @MrCas it does not change

Comment: @pcalkins it still fails to save in the wanted directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the mistake.

I wrote `brower` instead of `browser`...