# Python Selenium is not saving files

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I'm trying to save jpeg and pdf files with Selenium/geckodriver in Python.  I set preferences in Firefox to automatically save files of various types, but it's not resulting in any downloaded files.  I can log in and navigate to pages where I want to download the files with no trouble.

I consulted responses like [alexce's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251583/downloading-file-to-specified-location-with-selenium-and-python) and tried something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('broswer.download.folderList', 0)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', '/data')
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'image/jpeg')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

browser.get([website])
browser.get([another website with image])
browser.close()
```

When the browser is instantiated, and I look at about:config, it shows that those preferences were in fact set, but no files get saved anywhere I can find.

Have also tried:

- with and without the download.dir preference
- with values of 0, 1, and 2 for folderList
- from Spyder within Anaconda
- from PyCharm with Python 3.8.2 (different Windows 10 machine)
- with pdfs with saveToDisk = 'application/pdf'

Seems like this code worked well for others.  Not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to add comments so here is what i found when trying to get it to work.

Try to specify all file types and see it that works as the file type may be wrong. Also confirm you are using the latest version of firefox and Selenium as there is compatibility issues between many of the versions.

More info on compatibility can be found [here](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)

When you select a file to download does anything happen? Do you see an error

```
options = Options()
options.headless = headless

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', download_location)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/vnd.hzn-3d-crossword,video/3gpp,video/3gpp2,application/vnd.mseq,application/vnd.3m.post-it-notes,application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-large,application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-small,application/vnd.3gpp.pic-bw-var,application/vnd.3gp2.tcap,application/x-7z-compressed,application/x-abiword,application/x-ace-compressed,application/vnd.americandynamics.acc,application/vnd.acucobol,application/vnd.acucorp,audio/adpcm,application/x-authorware-bin,application/x-athorware-map,application/x-authorware-seg,application/vnd.adobe.air-application-installer-package+zip,application/x-shockwave-flash,application/vnd.adobe.fxp,application/pdf,application/vnd.cups-ppd,application/x-director,applicaion/vnd.adobe.xdp+xml,application/vnd.adobe.xfdf,audio/x-aac,application/vnd.ahead.space,application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azf,application/vnd.airzip.filesecure.azs,application/vnd.amazon.ebook,application/vnd.amiga.ami,applicatin/andrew-inset,application/vnd.android.package-archive,application/vnd.anser-web-certificate-issue-initiation,application/vnd.anser-web-funds-transfer-initiation,application/vnd.antix.game-component,application/vnd.apple.installe+xml,application/applixware,application/vnd.hhe.lesson-player,application/vnd.aristanetworks.swi,text/x-asm,application/atomcat+xml,application/atomsvc+xml,application/atom+xml,application/pkix-attr-cert,audio/x-aiff,video/x-msvieo,application/vnd.audiograph,image/vnd.dxf,model/vnd.dwf,text/plain-bas,application/x-bcpio,application/octet-stream,image/bmp,application/x-bittorrent,application/vnd.rim.cod,application/vnd.blueice.multipass,application/vnd.bm,application/x-sh,image/prs.btif,application/vnd.businessobjects,application/x-bzip,application/x-bzip2,application/x-csh,text/x-c,application/vnd.chemdraw+xml,text/css,chemical/x-cdx,chemical/x-cml,chemical/x-csml,application/vn.contact.cmsg,application/vnd.claymore,application/vnd.clonk.c4group,image/vnd.dvb.subtitle,application/cdmi-capability,application/cdmi-container,application/cdmi-domain,application/cdmi-object,application/cdmi-queue,applicationvnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config,application/vnd.cluetrust.cartomobile-config-pkg,image/x-cmu-raster,model/vnd.collada+xml,text/csv,application/mac-compactpro,application/vnd.wap.wmlc,image/cgm,x-conference/x-cooltalk,image/x-cmx,application/vnd.xara,application/vnd.cosmocaller,application/x-cpio,application/vnd.crick.clicker,application/vnd.crick.clicker.keyboard,application/vnd.crick.clicker.palette,application/vnd.crick.clicker.template,application/vn.crick.clicker.wordbank,application/vnd.criticaltools.wbs+xml,application/vnd.rig.cryptonote,chemical/x-cif,chemical/x-cmdf,application/cu-seeme,application/prs.cww,text/vnd.curl,text/vnd.curl.dcurl,text/vnd.curl.mcurl,text/vnd.crl.scurl,application/vnd.curl.car,application/vnd.curl.pcurl,application/vnd.yellowriver-custom-menu,application/dssc+der,application/dssc+xml,application/x-debian-package,audio/vnd.dece.audio,image/vnd.dece.graphic,video/vnd.dec.hd,video/vnd.dece.mobile,video/vnd.uvvu.mp4,video/vnd.dece.pd,video/vnd.dece.sd,video/vnd.dece.video,application/x-dvi,application/vnd.fdsn.seed,application/x-dtbook+xml,application/x-dtbresource+xml,application/vnd.dvb.ait,applcation/vnd.dvb.service,audio/vnd.digital-winds,image/vnd.djvu,application/xml-dtd,application/vnd.dolby.mlp,application/x-doom,application/vnd.dpgraph,audio/vnd.dra,application/vnd.dreamfactory,audio/vnd.dts,audio/vnd.dts.hd,imag/vnd.dwg,application/vnd.dynageo,application/ecmascript,application/vnd.ecowin.chart,image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-mmr,image/vnd.fujixerox.edmics-rlc,application/exi,application/vnd.proteus.magazine,application/epub+zip,message/rfc82,application/vnd.enliven,application/vnd.is-xpr,image/vnd.xiff,application/vnd.xfdl,application/emma+xml,application/vnd.ezpix-album,application/vnd.ezpix-package,image/vnd.fst,video/vnd.fvt,image/vnd.fastbidsheet,application/vn.denovo.fcselayout-link,video/x-f4v,video/x-flv,image/vnd.fpx,image/vnd.net-fpx,text/vnd.fmi.flexstor,video/x-fli,application/vnd.fluxtime.clip,application/vnd.fdf,text/x-fortran,application/vnd.mif,application/vnd.framemaker,imae/x-freehand,application/vnd.fsc.weblaunch,application/vnd.frogans.fnc,application/vnd.frogans.ltf,application/vnd.fujixerox.ddd,application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks,application/vnd.fujixerox.docuworks.binder,application/vnd.fujitu.oasys,application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys2,application/vnd.fujitsu.oasys3,application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysgp,application/vnd.fujitsu.oasysprs,application/x-futuresplash,application/vnd.fuzzysheet,image/g3fax,application/vnd.gmx,model/vn.gtw,application/vnd.genomatix.tuxedo,application/vnd.geogebra.file,application/vnd.geogebra.tool,model/vnd.gdl,application/vnd.geometry-explorer,application/vnd.geonext,application/vnd.geoplan,application/vnd.geospace,applicatio/x-font-ghostscript,application/x-font-bdf,application/x-gtar,application/x-texinfo,application/x-gnumeric,application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml,application/vnd.google-earth.kmz,application/vnd.grafeq,image/gif,text/vnd.graphviz,aplication/vnd.groove-account,application/vnd.groove-help,application/vnd.groove-identity-message,application/vnd.groove-injector,application/vnd.groove-tool-message,application/vnd.groove-tool-template,application/vnd.groove-vcar,video/h261,video/h263,video/h264,application/vnd.hp-hpid,application/vnd.hp-hps,application/x-hdf,audio/vnd.rip,application/vnd.hbci,application/vnd.hp-jlyt,application/vnd.hp-pcl,application/vnd.hp-hpgl,application/vnd.yamaha.h-script,application/vnd.yamaha.hv-dic,application/vnd.yamaha.hv-voice,application/vnd.hydrostatix.sof-data,application/hyperstudio,application/vnd.hal+xml,text/html,application/vnd.ibm.rights-management,application/vnd.ibm.securecontainer,text/calendar,application/vnd.iccprofile,image/x-icon,application/vnd.igloader,image/ief,application/vnd.immervision-ivp,application/vnd.immervision-ivu,application/reginfo+xml,text/vnd.in3d.3dml,text/vnd.in3d.spot,mode/iges,application/vnd.intergeo,application/vnd.cinderella,application/vnd.intercon.formnet,application/vnd.isac.fcs,application/ipfix,application/pkix-cert,application/pkixcmp,application/pkix-crl,application/pkix-pkipath,applicaion/vnd.insors.igm,application/vnd.ipunplugged.rcprofile,application/vnd.irepository.package+xml,text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor,application/java-archive,application/java-vm,application/x-java-jnlp-file,application/java-serializd-object,text/x-java-source,java,application/javascript,application/json,application/vnd.joost.joda-archive,video/jpm,image/jpeg,video/jpeg,application/vnd.kahootz,application/vnd.chipnuts.karaoke-mmd,application/vnd.kde.karbon,aplication/vnd.kde.kchart,application/vnd.kde.kformula,application/vnd.kde.kivio,application/vnd.kde.kontour,application/vnd.kde.kpresenter,application/vnd.kde.kspread,application/vnd.kde.kword,application/vnd.kenameaapp,applicatin/vnd.kidspiration,application/vnd.kinar,application/vnd.kodak-descriptor,application/vnd.las.las+xml,application/x-latex,application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.desktop,application/vnd.llamagraphics.life-balance.exchange+xml,application/vnd.jam,application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3,application/vnd.lotus-approach,application/vnd.lotus-freelance,application/vnd.lotus-notes,application/vnd.lotus-organizer,application/vnd.lotus-screencam,application/vnd.lotus-wordro,audio/vnd.lucent.voice,audio/x-mpegurl,video/x-m4v,application/mac-binhex40,application/vnd.macports.portpkg,application/vnd.osgeo.mapguide.package,application/marc,application/marcxml+xml,application/mxf,application/vnd.wolfrm.player,application/mathematica,application/mathml+xml,application/mbox,application/vnd.medcalcdata,application/mediaservercontrol+xml,application/vnd.mediastation.cdkey,application/vnd.mfer,application/vnd.mfmp,model/mesh,appliation/mads+xml,application/mets+xml,application/mods+xml,application/metalink4+xml,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabed.12,application/vnd.mcd,application/vnd.micrografx.flo,application/vnd.micrografx.igx,application/vnd.eszigno3+xml,application/x-msaccess,video/x-ms-asf,application/x-msdownload,application/vnd.ms-artgalry,application/vnd.ms-ca-compressed,application/vnd.ms-ims,application/x-ms-application,application/x-msclip,image/vnd.ms-modi,application/vnd.ms-fontobject,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excelsheet.binary.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-htmlhelp,application/x-mscardfile,application/vnd.ms-lrm,application/x-msmediaview,aplication/x-msmoney,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshw,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template,application/vnd.openxmformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template,application/x-msbinder,application/vnd.ms-officetheme,application/onenote,audio/vnd.ms-playready.media.pya,vdeo/vnd.ms-playready.media.pyv,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.addin.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slide.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroenabled.12,appliation/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroenabled.12,application/vnd.ms-project,application/x-mspublisher,application/x-msschedule,application/x-silverlight-app,application/vnd.ms-pki.stl,application/vnd.ms-pki.seccat,application/vn.visio,video/x-ms-wm,audio/x-ms-wma,audio/x-ms-wax,video/x-ms-wmx,application/x-ms-wmd,application/vnd.ms-wpl,application/x-ms-wmz,video/x-ms-wmv,video/x-ms-wvx,application/x-msmetafile,application/x-msterminal,application/msword,application/x-mswrite,application/vnd.ms-works,application/x-ms-xbap,application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument,audio/midi,application/vnd.ibm.minipay,application/vnd.ibm.modcap,application/vnd.jcp.javame.midlet-rms,application/vnd.tmobile-ivetv,application/x-mobipocket-ebook,application/vnd.mobius.mbk,application/vnd.mobius.dis,application/vnd.mobius.plc,application/vnd.mobius.mqy,application/vnd.mobius.msl,application/vnd.mobius.txf,application/vnd.mobius.daf,tex/vnd.fly,application/vnd.mophun.certificate,application/vnd.mophun.application,video/mj2,audio/mpeg,video/vnd.mpegurl,video/mpeg,application/mp21,audio/mp4,video/mp4,application/mp4,application/vnd.apple.mpegurl,application/vnd.msician,application/vnd.muvee.style,application/xv+xml,application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.data,application/vnd.nokia.n-gage.symbian.install,application/x-dtbncx+xml,application/x-netcdf,application/vnd.neurolanguage.nlu,application/vnd.na,application/vnd.noblenet-directory,application/vnd.noblenet-sealer,application/vnd.noblenet-web,application/vnd.nokia.radio-preset,application/vnd.nokia.radio-presets,text/n3,application/vnd.novadigm.edm,application/vnd.novadim.edx,application/vnd.novadigm.ext,application/vnd.flographit,audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp4800,audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp7470,audio/vnd.nuera.ecelp9600,application/oda,application/ogg,audio/ogg,video/ogg,application/vnd.oma.dd2+xml,applicatin/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web,application/oebps-package+xml,application/vnd.intu.qbo,application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension,application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat,audio/webm,video/webm,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.char,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.grapics,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation,application/vnd.oasis.opendocumen.presentation-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text,application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master,application/vnd.asis.opendocument.text-template,image/ktx,application/vnd.sun.xml.calc,application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template,application/vnd.sun.xml.draw,application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template,application/vnd.sun.xml.impress,application/vnd.sun.xl.impress.template,application/vnd.sun.xml.math,application/vnd.sun.xml.writer,application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global,application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template,application/x-font-otf,application/vnd.yamaha.openscoreformat.osfpvg+xml,application/vnd.osgi.dp,application/vnd.palm,text/x-pascal,application/vnd.pawaafile,application/vnd.hp-pclxl,application/vnd.picsel,image/x-pcx,image/vnd.adobe.photoshop,application/pics-rules,image/x-pict,application/x-chat,aplication/pkcs10,application/x-pkcs12,application/pkcs7-mime,application/pkcs7-signature,application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp,application/x-pkcs7-certificates,application/pkcs8,application/vnd.pocketlearn,image/x-portable-anymap,image/-portable-bitmap,application/x-font-pcf,application/font-tdpfr,application/x-chess-pgn,image/x-portable-graymap,image/png,image/x-portable-pixmap,application/pskc+xml,application/vnd.ctc-posml,application/postscript,application/xfont-type1,application/vnd.powerbuilder6,application/pgp-encrypted,application/pgp-signature,application/vnd.previewsystems.box,application/vnd.pvi.ptid1,application/pls+xml,application/vnd.pg.format,application/vnd.pg.osasli,tex/prs.lines.tag,application/x-font-linux-psf,application/vnd.publishare-delta-tree,application/vnd.pmi.widget,application/vnd.quark.quarkxpress,application/vnd.epson.esf,application/vnd.epson.msf,application/vnd.epson.ssf,applicaton/vnd.epson.quickanime,application/vnd.intu.qfx,video/quicktime,application/x-rar-compressed,audio/x-pn-realaudio,audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin,application/rsd+xml,application/vnd.rn-realmedia,application/vnd.realvnc.bed,applicatin/vnd.recordare.musicxml,application/vnd.recordare.musicxml+xml,application/relax-ng-compact-syntax,application/vnd.data-vision.rdz,application/rdf+xml,application/vnd.cloanto.rp9,application/vnd.jisp,application/rtf,text/richtex,application/vnd.route66.link66+xml,application/rss+xml,application/shf+xml,application/vnd.sailingtracker.track,image/svg+xml,application/vnd.sus-calendar,application/sru+xml,application/set-payment-initiation,application/set-reistration-initiation,application/vnd.sema,application/vnd.semd,application/vnd.semf,application/vnd.seemail,application/x-font-snf,application/scvp-vp-request,application/scvp-vp-response,application/scvp-cv-request,application/svp-cv-response,application/sdp,text/x-setext,video/x-sgi-movie,application/vnd.shana.informed.formdata,application/vnd.shana.informed.formtemplate,application/vnd.shana.informed.interchange,application/vnd.shana.informed.package,application/thraud+xml,application/x-shar,image/x-rgb,application/vnd.epson.salt,application/vnd.accpac.simply.aso,application/vnd.accpac.simply.imp,application/vnd.simtech-mindmapper,application/vnd.commonspace,application/vnd.ymaha.smaf-audio,application/vnd.smaf,application/vnd.yamaha.smaf-phrase,application/vnd.smart.teacher,application/vnd.svd,application/sparql-query,application/sparql-results+xml,application/srgs,application/srgs+xml,application/sml+xml,application/vnd.koan,text/sgml,application/vnd.stardivision.calc,application/vnd.stardivision.draw,application/vnd.stardivision.impress,application/vnd.stardivision.math,application/vnd.stardivision.writer,application/vnd.tardivision.writer-global,application/vnd.stepmania.stepchart,application/x-stuffit,application/x-stuffitx,application/vnd.solent.sdkm+xml,application/vnd.olpc-sugar,audio/basic,application/vnd.wqd,application/vnd.symbian.install,application/smil+xml,application/vnd.syncml+xml,application/vnd.syncml.dm+wbxml,application/vnd.syncml.dm+xml,application/x-sv4cpio,application/x-sv4crc,application/sbml+xml,text/tab-separated-values,image/tiff,application/vnd.to.intent-module-archive,application/x-tar,application/x-tcl,application/x-tex,application/x-tex-tfm,application/tei+xml,text/plain,application/vnd.spotfire.dxp,application/vnd.spotfire.sfs,application/timestamped-data,applicationvnd.trid.tpt,application/vnd.triscape.mxs,text/troff,application/vnd.Trueapp,application/x-font-ttf,text/turtle,application/vnd.umajin,application/vnd.uoml+xml,application/vnd.unity,application/vnd.ufdl,text/uri-list,application/nd.uiq.theme,application/x-ustar,text/x-uuencode,text/x-vcalendar,text/x-vcard,application/x-cdlink,application/vnd.vsf,model/vrml,application/vnd.vcx,model/vnd.mts,model/vnd.vtu,application/vnd.visionary,video/vnd.vivo,applicatin/ccxml+xml,,application/voicexml+xml,application/x-wais-source,application/vnd.wap.wbxml,image/vnd.wap.wbmp,audio/x-wav,application/davmount+xml,application/x-font-woff,application/wspolicy+xml,image/webp,application/vnd.webturb,application/widget,application/winhlp,text/vnd.wap.wml,text/vnd.wap.wmlscript,application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc,application/vnd.wordperfect,application/vnd.wt.stf,application/wsdl+xml,image/x-xbitmap,image/x-xpixmap,image/x-xwindowump,application/x-x509-ca-cert,application/x-xfig,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,application/xcap-diff+xml,application/xenc+xml,application/patch-ops-error+xml,application/resource-lists+xml,application/rls-services+xml,aplication/resource-lists-diff+xml,application/xslt+xml,application/xop+xml,application/x-xpinstall,application/xspf+xml,application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml,chemical/x-xyz,text/yaml,application/yang,application/yin+xml,application/vnd.ul,application/zip,application/vnd.handheld-entertainment+xml,application/vnd.zzazz.deck+xml')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=gecko_driver, firefox_profile=profile)
```