# downloading a file from a webpage using python script without url , calling onClick function

Tags: javascript, python, html

There is a webpage which have a link "Click to Download" Clicking which a file is downloaded . 
I can download this file manually by going to webpage and clicking on this link however I need to download this file via a python script .

If i see the source i can see the anchor tag is will run a js function

```html
<a class="download-data-link1" onclick=" document.forms['dataform'].submit()" style="cursor:pointer; vertical-align: middle;">Download in csv</a>
```

But i dont know the url of csv file and i am looking for a way to download it via python .

I know we can download a file if we have url using httplib but couldnt understand how to get a file without url .

Tried few things like in header added 
'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename="data.csv"'}

but it dosent seems to work . Any ideas ?

Comment: It has to python? Because links have a tendency (especially nowadays) to be added to the DOM later on, or to respond to certain events, triggered by the user, which makes a headless browser a better option here (IMHO). I'd look into PhantomJS or similar tools

Comment: Well even if its not python maybe something which i can invoke from python script . Just saw http://phantomjs.org/ as per your suggestion . Need to study it further

Comment: `PhantomJS` can be automated through `selenium` - so it can be python.

Comment: @paarthbatra: [Selenium + chromedriver](https://github.com/EVODelavega/gp-scripts/tree/master/codeception) would be an option, too (link is to 2 scripts: get-drivers downloads what you need, `codeception-start` starts/stops selenium), you can then use that setup with a python script quite easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic options can be applied here:

- mimic the logic involved in the `onclick()` call - in your case, make the `dataform` form submission using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), or [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
- high-level approach - automate a real browser, headless (`PhantomJS`) or not, using [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) - find the link and click it:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
  driver.get('url here')

  driver.find_element_by_class_name('download-data-link1').click()
  ```

Though, as far as I understand, clicking the link would trigger a "Download" browser dialog to appear - then `PhantomJS` is not an option since it doesn't support downloads. In case of `Chrome` or `Firefox` you would need to tweak browser capabilities to automatically download files without opening the popup, see:

- [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)
- [Firefox + Selenium WebDriver and download a csv file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759762/firefox-selenium-webdriver-and-download-a-csv-file-automatically)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for your answers but I want to add, how i implemented it.

1. First of all you can create a firefox profile. To do that:
2. Close all firefox browsers
3. go to cmd prompt and execute firefox.exe -P
4. create a profile and note down the name of the folder where new profile is created

You can set some options for your profile here, like - automatically download these kind of files from content etc.

Now Download selenium for python and use below code

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

download_dir="D:\a"

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(<profile directory here as in step 4>)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_dir)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium")
# you can use your url here 
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("selenium-2").click()
# Use your method to identify class or link text here
browser.close();
```

Hope this may help others :)