# How to trigger a js function on a website using Python? Parsing

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

**Hi all!** I encountered such a problem, when #parsing a site, I need to collect links and text, but the problem is that the link is not written directly, but through the #js function in the #html code, then roughly speaking, I need to trigger the js function by passing her parameters. And yes, I need to call this function (I don’t know how). I can’t use Selenium, I write the code in #Python

**This is my first time on the forum, and I’m just starting to master parsing, I would be very grateful for your answer**

```
function submit(key, title, value)
    {
        var url = document.location.href;
        if (document.location.href.indexOf('#') != -1)
            url = document.location.href.substring(0, document.location.href.indexOf('#'));
        if (value != '')
            document.location.href = url + "#" + value;
        else
            document.location.href = url;
        var form = document.getElementById('PostForm');
        form.innerHTML = "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Key\">";
        form.innerHTML += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Title\">";
        document.forms[1].Key.value = key;
        document.forms[1].Title.value = title;
        document.forms[1].action = "Groups.aspx";
        document.forms[1].submit();
    }
```

```
<a href="javascript:submit('RJuzPlvdavwzyOu12R7PKQ==','название товара....','0');">название товара....</a>
```

Comment: Similar question with the solution to use a headless browser.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147213/downloading-a-file-from-a-webpage-using-python-script-without-url-calling-oncl  - another for selenium: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010059/execute-js-code-on-page-from-python

Comment: Another similar question which suggests using [tag:pyv8] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136319/executing-javascript-from-python

Comment: I need it without simulating a browser, it is advisable to use the request library

Comment: Note that a lot of answers predate Playwright and instead talk about using Selenium: you probably want Playwright these days (which offers more browser options, and supports more of the modern JS patterns).