# Get the href generated from some javascript attached to a button with selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.4

I'm using selenium to pull some automated phone reporting from our phone system (Barracuda Cudatel, very nice small business system but it doesn't have an API for what I need). There is a button on the report page that has some javascript attached to it on a click listener that then tells the browser to download the file.

Obviously selenium isn't really designed to pull files like this, however all I'm trying to do is get the href of the url that would have been sent to the browser. I can then turn around and use the session credentials with requests to pull the file and do processing on it.

How do I do the following (In Python):

1. Query for the event listener for 'click'
2. Fire off the javascript
3. Get the resulting URL

Edit: I'm aware download location can be configured on the browser in selenium however I'm not interested in completing this task in that fashion. This is running against a selenium grid of 20 machines and the request could be routed to any of them. Since I can't pull the file through selenium I'm going to just pull it directly with requests.

Code I'm twiddling with is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep
dcap = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://gridurl:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=dcap)
driver.get("http://cudatelurl")
driver.find_element_by_name("__auth_user").send_keys("user")
driver.find_element_by_name("__auth_pass").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_id("manage").click()
driver.get("http://cudatelurl/#!/cudatel/cdrs")
sleep(5)
date_dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cui-content-inner"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/select'))
date_dropdown.select_by_value("last_week")

# This is the element that has javascript attached to it the click register is 
# button.widgetType.csvButtonWidget.widgetized.actionButtonType.table-action
# but I'd prefer to not hard code it
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cui-content-inner"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]') 

print(driver.get_cookies())
print(driver.title)
sleep(10)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still approach it with selenium by configuring the target directory for the file of a specific mime-type to be *automatically downloaded* (without the Save As dialog), see:

- [Download PDF files automatically in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver](http://yizeng.me/2014/05/23/download-pdf-files-automatically-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver/)
- [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)
- [Firefox + Selenium WebDriver and download a csv file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759762/firefox-selenium-webdriver-and-download-a-csv-file-automatically)

Comment: I'm not interested in doing the request in this fashion. This is working off a grid that could pull from any of 20 different boxes.

Comment: @RyanM alright then. Show the HTML code of the link and the underlying js logic behind the click. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to pull the registered listeners from the element if that is possible. Alternatively get a list of all registered listeners.